# PDO SQLite: unable to open database file

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, sqlite, doctrine-orm

I create a project in Symfony and encountered a [bug #57785](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57785). Apparently a bug and remains unresolved.

Who knows a way around this bug?

**I will explain the problem**

I created a portable app. Such application, the user normally installs on the `Desktop` or `My Documents`.

Example bad path for Russian:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Администратор\Рабочий стол\
C:\Documents and Settings\Администратор\Мои документы\
```

I can restrict the user to install the application in such a directory, but it is bad practice.

Сan change assembly `dsn` in the package `doctrine/dbal`, but it is a very tough decision that will not always work:

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver::_constructPdoDsn(array $params)
{
    $dsn = 'sqlite:';
    if (isset($params['path'])) {
        $dsn .= iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $params['path']);
    } else if (isset($params['memory'])) {
        $dsn .= ':memory:';
    }

    return $dsn;
}
```

Necessary get the Doctrine database driver and replace path to database file after changing the encoding.

```
$conn = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getConnection();
$new_path = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $conn->getParams()['path']);
// further necessary change connection params
```

Comment: use a path with ascii chars, like C:\test or /home/user/opt/test ¸.

Comment: @pce i wrote below. I cannot control the directory location of the program

Answer (score 2):

I know. Just don't use fancy catalog names on your server.

```
/var/www/project/db/
```

would be either sane and readable by any software

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot control the directory location of the program. Path to the program not only can, but probably will contain invalid characters.